# Cannot set value of select element in internet explorer 10 or 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, select

When ever I try to set the value of a select element like select.value='somevalue'; This no longer works in IE 10 or 11.

The JQuery version will work but not the raw JavaScript.

**Does not work in IE 10 or 11**

```
selFractInchOpts.value = '25';
```

**Works in all browsers.**

```
$(selFractInchOpts).val('25');
```

What is the correct way to set the value of a select element in 10 or 11 Internet Explorer?

**--This works--**

```
    var resetSelectValue = function (b) {

        var fract = (b.size.widthInches - ~~b.size.widthInches) + '',
                     width = (~~b.size.widthInches) + '',
                     o;

        $(selBayWidthOptions).val(width);
        $(selFractInchOpts).val(fract);

        selFractInchOpts.onchange = selectBayWidthOpts;
        selBayWidthOptions.onchange = selectBayWidthOpts;
    };
```

**--This does not work--**

```
            var resetSelectValue = function (b) {

                var fract = (b.size.widthInches - ~~b.size.widthInches) + '',
                             width = (~~b.size.widthInches) + '',
                             o;

                selBayWidthOptions.value = width;
                selFractInchOpts.value = fract;

                selFractInchOpts.onchange = selectBayWidthOpts;
                selBayWidthOptions.onchange = selectBayWidthOpts;
            };
```

Comment: What is the value of the variable `selFractInchOpts`?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the HTML as well.

Comment: The selFractInchOpts is a HTMLSelectElement. Lets just say the selFractInchOpts select element has 30 values 1 - 30 is the values, each value being one of the numbers between 1 - 30. Now in IE 10 and 11 I cannot set the value of the selFractInchOpts like before, as in, selFractInchOpts.value = '25'; Whats going on here? I'm accustom to setting the selectedIndex and the .value of the select element, now I can no longer do the .value in IE 10 or 11.

Comment: I can get it to work in IE 11: http://jsfiddle.net/qM5S5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that jQuery someSelect.val(x) is an entire function that iterates over all the options from the select, a quick and dirty option would be:

```
function setSelectValue(theSelect,value){
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(theSelect.children,function(el){if(el.value==value.toString()){el.selected=true}});
}

...your code where you need to set the element by its value
setSelectValue(theSelect,theValueToSelect);
```

Hope this helps.